# dynamically setting DataSource properties for Spring jdbc

Tags: spring, jdbc

I'm using spring jdbc and I want my application to connect to different DBMS as oracle,mySQL, SAS etc.
the application should work on different systems, so the connection properties are not priorly known.

Ideally, the user will be able to select connection type from a list and then set the connection properties (username,password...)

Can you please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jdbc/spring-jdbctemplate-example/

There you can see the normal jdbctemplate use. As you can see the dao has got the datasource injected: you can basically do the same, but you need not to set the org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource properties in the applicationContext.xml. You will do it at runtime according to user choice. That basically means all the daos have to get the datasource needed params in input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) 
I agree with the fact that datasource should not be configured in the application context, but technically how to do this ? thx.
ps: it's my first application with spring and jsf +primefaces